# Usar IndexFieldNames no FMX

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, índices

Estou tentando usar o `IndexFieldNames` dentro do FMX para organizar os dados de acordo com a coluna porém ao chamar o método `HeaderClick`, não consigo pegar o nome da Coluna e somente o índice dela. Usando Delphi 10.3

Gostaria de saber como posso pegar o nome da coluna pra inserir no `IndexFieldNames`
Segue um pedaço do meu código.

```
procedure TFConTitulos.GDTitulosHeaderClick(Column: TColumn);
var

Number : integer;
Name: string;

begin
  Number:= Column.Index;{ so consegui pegar o indice da columa selecionada}
Name:= {codigo vai aqui }
  UDM.FDConTiti.Close;

  UDM.FDConTiti.IndexFieldNames := Name;

  UDM.FDConTiti.Open;

end;
```

Comment: Esse FDConTiti é uma TFDConnection ou uma TFDTable/TFDQuery?

Comment: Ele é um  TFDQuery  testei a atribuição nele diretamente e funciona, então meu problema é capturar o nome do Field da coluna. Ou seja estou precisando do comando semelhante ao VCL `Column.FieldName` para FMX.

Answer (score 0):

Solução que encontrei. Não é a melhor mas ajudou.

```
  Number:= Column.Index;
  Name := GDTitulos.ColumnByIndex(Number).Header;

  case Number of

  1: Name:= 'ID_TITULO';
  4: Name:= 'NOME_FANTASIA';
  5: Name:= 'NUMERO_NOTA';
  9: Name:= 'DATA_VENC';
  12: Name:= 'VALOR_T_TITULO';

  end;

  UDM.FDConTiti.Close;
  UDM.FDConTiti.IndexFieldNames:= Name;
```